# Python Django: how to select the index type?

Tags: python, django

As stated in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index, you can add indexes to your table using `db_index=True`. But how do you force hash vs btree indexes?

Comment: You don't set `db_index=True` and add the index manually in your schema migration.

Comment: No because Index type is database specific. All modern database management systems support database index so did Django. On the other hand index type changes according to database management system and setting index type in `Model` layer of an application is the wrong approach.

Best possible solution is adding this to migration file as @iklinac mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has no implemented particular index type selection through models.

Workaround would be to create empty migration and write SQL statement in your migration for consistency

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/

```
manage.py makemigrations --empty app
```

Inside of migration in operations put following

```
migrations.RunSQL('Query to add index')
```

[RunSQL docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

Comment: Your first line assume that I'm starting from zero, which isn't necessarily the case. Regarding your suggested solution, can it be rolled back? Is Django smart enough to parse the query that adds indices and reverse it?

Comment: If you add up SQL for reverse migration yes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/migration-operations/#runsql  Also to note out that empty migration creates new migration after your last migration for following app

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work well. If I already have a constraint on that same field, the creating the index replaces the key name and can't then be rolled back

Comment: What is database type you use

Comment: MySQL. I had something like this `KEY key_name (user_id), CONSTRAINT foreign_key_constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user (id)`. Then I used your response to create migration that has `sql=["create index index_name using hash on table_name (user_id)"]`. This caused the `key_name` to get modified to `index_name`. It's all good, but when I use `reverse_sql=["drop index index_name on table_name"]` it gives an error that I can't delete the key because the foreign key constraint requires a key.

Comment: To be fair this is more a DB problem than Django. To reproduce. Create a foreign table named `auth_user` with a column named `user_id`. Then create a temp table that has `user_id`: `create table temp (id int not null, primary key(id), user_id int(11) default null);` then add FK constraint `alter table temp add foreign key key_name (user_id) references auth_user (id);` then add index `create index index_name using hash on temp (user_id);`, you will see that `key_name` gets changed to `index_name`. Now if you try to drop index you get error `drop index index_name on temp;`

Comment: With constraint and before adding the index you have `KEY key_name (user_id)` and after adding the index you have `KEY index_name (user_id) USING HASH`

Comment: So to revert migration back you just need to alter or create index instead of dropping it down because you had index before. Only 1 index can be on 1 selection. That is why by creating index you are actually deleting one on that selection that was there before. Foreign key needs key so you cannot delete it you should create it again without hash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134486/discussion-between-iklinac-and-oneloop).

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed a lot since the question was asked. It is now possible to define an index in the model layer through the metaclass of your model (at least since django 1.11):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/

For example:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import HashIndex
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        indexes = (HashIndex(fields=('name',)),)
```