# Postgres hash index with unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique

With Postgres 10 properly supporting hash index, I would like to use hash index for id lookup (hash index is smaller in size compared to btree and theoretically faster).

I have a table

```
create table t (id int);
create unique index on t using hash (id);
```

But I got the following:

`ERROR: access method "hash" does not support unique indexes`

Why does hash index not allow unique constraint?
Are there ways to circumvent this?

Answer (score 16):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-unique.html) leaves no room for doubt:

> Currently, only B-tree indexes can be declared unique.

There was a [discussion on the hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6318fb86-0a64-61e7-e4e2-714db2b3407a%40anastigmatix.net) about this recently, and it was concluded that it wouldn't be simple to add the capability to allow `UNIQUE` hash indexes.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this using an exclusion constraint:

```sql
create table t (id int);
alter table t add constraint c exclude using hash (id with =);
```

Comment: Would you know how the size would compare with the unique index? I'm assuming it would be less but have you checked? Also do you know how the exclusion index would perform on a billion rows?

Comment: The constraint itself should have little or no impact on storage requirements. I’ve used a hash index for an exclusion constraint in this manner on a table with a few hundred million rows and performance was very good. YMMV.

Comment: @jbg how did you do upsert? I have a trouble with syntax `conn.execute(
            f"""INSERT INTO {TABLE_NAME} VALUES ($1, $2) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
                SET value = ($2)""",
            hash_id,
            str_profile,
        )` gives me `there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`

Comment: @LukaszMadon Name the constraint in the `ON CONFLICT` clause instead of making Postgres infer it from the column (which only works with unique indexes, not with exclusion constraints). In the example in my answer it would be `ON CONFLICT (c) DO ...`. See the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Comment: thanks for the reply, I came to the same conclusion. `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cnp_profiles_id_excl DO UPDATE` which results in `WrongObjectTypeError: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE not supported with exclusion constraints` I can't use hash indexes with this kind of upserts.

Comment: It makes some sense, since _in general_ there could be multiple rows that conflicted when using an exclusion constraint (even though in this specific case it would always be one row), in which case it wouldn't be clear which conflicting row should be updated.

Comment: The create index command isn't needed - the constraint creation already creates an index.

Comment: @Elifarley good catch! updated

Comment: @LukaszMadon just simply create another unique constraint for this column: `alter table t add constraint unique_your_column_name unique (your_column_name); ` then you feel free to call `upsert_all .... unique_by: :your_column_name ) `

Comment: There's a another issue in addition to the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` one: you can't reference the column using a foreign key constraint. @Siwei: that would create a btree index which is what we're trying to avoid. Though evidently avoiding it seems like a bad idea at this point.

Answer (score 0):

why not just simply add a constraint for this column ?

```
create table t (id int);
create index on t using hash (id);

-- simply create a new constraint for this column, do not mix it with hash index
alter table t add constraint unique_id unique (id);
```

Comment: Because constraint would create btree index. In case of long (about 3k) strings, btree would fail!

Answer (score 0):

Very old idea

create unique index on links (cast(md5(url) as uuid));

I'm trying it now

UPD. It's slow like it's recalculating every sum on every insert.

UPD2. Adding functional unique index does not speed up SEARCH on the column.

To find the string in question one should either search by the same cast or add a hash index.