# How do I specify type of index in django? (btree vs hash vs etc)

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, model

Like the title says, how do I specify the type of index I want on a field in a model in django?

```
class Person:
     ...
     age = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
```

What now? How do I ensure that it is a `btree index` and not a `hash index`? Is this process automated by using some large table that Django uses to determine the optimal index type internally? Ideally, I would like a manual way to change these settings.

Comment: django doesnt fulfill that wish for you, it depends on your database what is the indexing it has as default, the default indexing is used when you make db_index=true in models

Comment: @Exprator do you know of any good resources that give the default index types for each field type in mysql?

Comment: follow one indexing for a project, else it will be a problem, if you make different indexing for all fields and tables'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django defaults to creating `btree` indexes whenever you specify `index=True`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/indexes/

I note you're using MySQL; but if you're using PostgreSQL, you can specify certain other index types on certain types of fields:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/

This answer gives information on how you can override the `btree` default in MySQL, should you ever need to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288059/1394697